# How to find a Windows Store App's SID?

Tags: windows, facebook, windows-store-apps

I am trying to integrate facebook into a Windows Store App.

I have created a new FB App and started working through the steps described in this blog post. http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/facebook-login-for-windows-store-apps/

​​

Here is where I ran into a problem. Step 2 describes how to obtain a Windows SID for an App that has yet to be published. However my app is already published. Does anyone know how to obtain a SID for an app that is already published in the Windows Store?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions in this post should help you find how to locate SID for published app: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465407.aspx

It's listed under step 3 for obtaining the credentials for your app. Here are the steps:

1. Go to the Windows Store apps page of the Windows Dev Center and sign in with your Microsoft account.
2. Once you have signed in, click the **Dashboard link**.
3. On the Dashboard, select **Submit an app**.
4. On the **Submit an app** page, select **App name**.
5. Select the **Services** link.
6. On the **Services** page, select the **Live Services** link found under the **Microsoft Azure Mobile Services** section.
7. On the **Push notifications and Live Connect services info** page, select **Identifying your app**.
8. The **Identifying your app** page gives you an identity element to include in your app's manifest. Open your manifest in a text editor and add that element as the page instructs.
   9.Click the **Authenticating your service** link at the bottom of that same **Identifying your app** page.
9. The **Authenticating your service** page provides your security identifier (SID) and client secret.

Answer (score 1):

I see it's an old post, but I guess it's better to show a simpler solution, which is the one told by microsoft in this thread: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/view-app-identity-details

You can just go to your application from the developer dashboard, then on the left you should expand the "**App Management**" option and choose "**App Identity**". There you can find many informations, including the App SID.